# How to Center Crop an Images on Web using CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, web

Got some images with different sizes and I want to make some thumbnail out of them. If I use overflow:hidden the output image would be the top left of the original image, while I want it to be the exact center of Image, as pixels I want it to be.Been searching for this for a while, but nothing really useful ...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an `img`, you can use a `div` with the image as the background, and use the CSS `background-position` property to center it. Or you could use an `img` inside a `div` with `overflow: hidden` and use a margin on the image to center it.

But FYI, thumbnails should be generated server-side, otherwise you're sending the whole image anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but it's still Off-line and there is no server to do that, Also I do want to send the whole image and then resize it, cause the user will open the image. 

this div method is pretty good and simple, thanks. any other methods would be great too as I have to edit the whole Script to make the images div background ...

Answer (score 0):

So, is your thumbnail just a tiny portion of the whole image? Why not resize image in the server and display it inside image tag with a predefined size? You can skip the server side resizing if your images aren't very large and just do the following: `<img src="image.jpg" alt="Some image" height="42" width="42" />`. Just change the image size to whatever you prefer.

Comment: well, it smashes the ratio and image would look like a total mess, but, Thank you anyway :)